# Update table based on other 2 related tables

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have a strange problem. I got some data for cities, regions and countries in CSV format and imported them into MySQL tables.

I have 3 tables and their fields

```
1. City    : id, name, country_code, region_number
2. Region  : region_number, country_code, name
3. Country : country_code, name
```

Now things get a little complicated, as I added an auto-generated id column to the region table, so the region x for country y would be unique.

The thing is: Now i am trying to update city field region_number to hold this unique value (the new id column in region) so I can have relations city->region.

The relation region->country or country->region is OK.

Is it possible to write an update query that would update city region_code (or fill some new column, eg. region_id) with correct values?

If not an query, what could I use to get the correct values into the cities table?

I have arround 3 million records!

Comment: how do you know which region a city belongs to? do you have some values in city.region_number already or you have to fill it?

Comment: There are already some values, but not the unique ones. The current values refer for example to the region 02, but this region can exist in any country (so, not unique)

Comment: but is the combination of city.country_code and city.region_number unique? so you can refer to a single region?

Comment: The combination of these 2 yes, but this would over-complicate my design / php orm - doctrine. The simpler solution would be if I could get those unique auto-generated region id-s to the region field in city

Comment: I deleted my answer before because I wasn't sure, but now I've undeleted it, i think it should do what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understant correctly, I think you are looking for something like this:

```
UPDATE
  City inner join Region
  on City.country_code = Region.country_code
     and City.region_number = Region.region_number
SET
  City.new_column = Region.id
```

However, since there's a relation already between City and Region, I am not sure this is the right thing to do, since it will make the table not normalized.

Answer (score 1):

> Now i am trying to update city field region_number to not hold this unique value

The only way you can do this is if the region_number uniquely identifies each region - and if that's already the case then you are wasting your time by creating redundant references. Although frankly, if these really are your table structures, there's no reason for using surrogate keys. And if there's no reason for using surrogate keys then the region and country table are redundant.

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo. The "not" was not intended here

Comment: `but this would over-complicate my design / php orm - doctrine` - no it won't a discussion of of the overuse of trivial ORM goes way beyond the scope of stackoverflow, but try to remember patterns are what code is - not what it should be.